# Validate uniqueness still blocking after a delete_all command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a rails model with a constraint on 2 keys

```
validates :worker, uniqueness: { scope: :job }
```

I deleted all entries for this model with a

```
Model.delete_all
```

But when I try to add a new entity with the same combination as before I get an error. Like the index was not reset?

Comment: Did you check if there were records still present even after delete_all?

Comment: Please paste the error.

Comment: what's the relationship between worker and job? Is there a join table that needs to be cleared out as well?

Comment: It justt says that WorkerJobConnection Exists and then it makes a rollback. When i do a WorkerJobConnection.all it returns an empty array. The relationship table is the WorkerJobConnection.

Comment: I tried resetting the db and recreate the problem. But this time i used destroy not delete on the record. After this i could re insert a new entity with the same two keys. Is that because destroy updates the index as well and delete don´t?